# Cakephp css and js 404 compression error

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a website and for some reason it started coming up with 404 errors not being able to find some JavaScript and stylesheet files.

Images are also throwing up 404's as the compression seems not to work.

I thought it has to do with the `.htaccess` file however it looks okay.

Below is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
## ROOT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.*********\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.*********/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .css

</IfModule>

## APP FOLDER
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>

## WEBROOT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]    
    RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^js - [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddType text/plain .png

So would it be the minify plugin that would be causing the js and css errors? Or the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: are your css and js files are loaded correctly ? and have you given correct path for their location ?  confirm that first.

Answer (score 0):

Are your assets added in your

1. webroot/css
2. webroot/img
3. webroot/js

folders respectively?

if they are then all you need to reference them is use the path *"/css/{css file name}"* etc...